# Firestore crashes while trying to create a document

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with a FireStore, hope some of you could help me.
I'm trying to create a document this way:

```
class FireStoreUtils: NSObject {

   static let defaultUtils = FireStoreUtils()
   var db = Firestore.firestore()
   
   var fireStoreSettings = FirestoreSettings.init()

   override init() {
       
       super.init()
       fireStoreSettings.host = FireStoreParameters.host
       fireStoreSettings.isSSLEnabled = FireStoreParameters.sslEnabled
       fireStoreSettings.isPersistenceEnabled = FireStoreParameters.persistenceEnabled
       fireStoreSettings.cacheSizeBytes = Int64(FireStoreParameters.cacheSizeBytes)
       db.settings = fireStoreSettings

   }
   weak var delegate:FireStoreUtilsDelegate?
       func addNewUser(userData userDictionary: [String: Any],userId uId: String)  {
       
       do {
           
           let table = self.db.collection("Collection_name")
           let documentRef = table.document(uId)
           try? documentRef.setData(userDictionary, completion: { (error) in
               
               if (error != nil) {
                   
                   self.delegate?.didFailToPerformOperation(errorMessage: error?.localizedDescription)
               }
               else {
                   
                   self.delegate?.didSucceedToPerformOperation(message: "Success")
               }
           })
       }
       catch let error {
           
           self.delegate?.didFailToPerformOperation(errorMessage: error.localizedDescription)
           
           
       }
       
   }
```

But from some reason executing setData I get the following crash
**assertion failed: 0 == pthread_setspecific(tls->key, (void*)value)**

I tried to use FireStore logs but the last log message I got is
**2021-01-17 18:55:12.114707+0200  7.3.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] Creating Firestore stub.**

I added Firestore manually and din't use nor Swift PM or Pods, because both of the didn't work with FirebaseAuth in pod file.
It starts to look like everything is dead end.
If somebody knows what's going on or got similar problem, please,help!
Thank you,

Maria.

Comment: We build firebase projects all of the time using Cocoapods so I would be curious as to why that didn't work. More than likely Firebase is not being initialized correctly but it could be a number of other things as well. I would really go back to basics and get the podfile working as once that works, implementing Firestore is snap.

Comment: I use SwiftGRPC and it looks like grpc-Core dependency doesn't have the same version that FireStore has, so it makes conflicts and prevent it from to be installed using Cocoa Pods.Unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm. SwiftGRPC appears toi be depreciated from what I can see and replaced with grpc-Swift. Did you install it with cocoapods? [grpc-Swift](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift)? If not, you may want to try that and then Firestore. I don't see any correlation between the two so it's not clear where the error is, other than perhaps one of the settings in your code (or perhaps missing settings). Again, getting the podfile correct may be a solution as well.

Comment: @Jay It seems that you was right. I'm steel struggling to make GRPC calls work like they worked with SwiftGRPC, but at least I didn't get that assertion. Thank you!